# Contacting a potential advisor: Where should I go from here?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, email, communication

About two and a half weeks ago, I contacted five potential advisors at a school that I am planning to do my master’s at. Three of them got back to me and said they are not expecting any graduate students next year, but seemed interested in me (they said they would consider me for the future). Two others got back to me, very interested, and I scheduled phone calls with them. I have one phone call next week.

However, I had a phone call with a potential advisor nearly two weeks ago. It was really casual and he seemed very interested. He suggested an area that I could do a project in. We exchanged a few emails after the phone call where we discussed what I could potentially research. He sent me a link that I checked out. He said that he had some students gathering data in the area that I said I was interested in; so we could use some of that data. I responded with “that sounds compelling, I would be interested in doing research in that area”.

That was the end of our email exchanges. I am not really sure where to go from here. He never confirmed that I will be a graduate student, but also seems like he is very interested. Should I expect him to make the next contact or should I contact him? I am not really sure what I would say since I threw the ball over to him in my last email. I have to apply for a scholarship by the end of January though (which includes a research proposal) and he knows this...

Comment: Did you ask him what you need to do to actually apply?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning No because I apply through the school and all the information is on the school’s website. I need a statement of intent indicating my research interests (which I discussed a BIT with my potential supervisor) and career goals. But before sending my application I need to apply for a scholarship. In that application, I need a detailed description of a research proposal which we didn’t discuss at all.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the problem is. Why not just tell him you'd like to apply and ask him about a research proposal?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning He already knows I’d like to apply. Basically, I don’t know where I am with him yet. I don’t know if he agreed to be my advisor. He seemed very enthusiastic about it when I spoke with him, but he never told me one way or the other “yes, I will be your advisor. Go ahead with the application”. We’ve talked briefly about some project ideas, but for the scholarship application I need to write down an actual project proposal. So I’m just wondering what I should say to him when I email him?